# What are those pipe symbols for in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

What are the pipe symbols for in Ruby?

I'm learning Ruby and RoR, coming from a PHP and Java background, but I keep coming across code like this:

```
def new 
  @post = Post.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml { render :xml => @post }
  end
end
```

What is the `|format|` part doing? What's the equivalent syntax of these pipe symbols in PHP/Java?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

They are the variables yielded to the block.

```
def this_method_takes_a_block
  yield(5)
end

this_method_takes_a_block do |num|
  puts num
end
```

Which outputs "5". A more arcane example:

```
def this_silly_method_too(num)
  yield(num + 5)
end

this_silly_method_too(3) do |wtf|
  puts wtf + 1
end
```

The output is "9".

Comment: where does `wtf` go when the `|wtf|` block ends?

Comment: It is scoped to the block, so it's unavailable outside of it. In other words: it goes away.

Comment: If it mutable? It has to be, otherwise I haven't any clue how Vagrantfile's can use them as a configuration method.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. It's just a named reference to an object.

Comment: Mutable meaning you can  persistently change the named reference, as opposed to immutable which cannot be changed, eg the variable would have to be reassigned the mutated value if you wanted to persist a change.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can change what 'wtf' points to within the block, and/or what kind of error you might get if you can't. But it can change over the course of the running program, since it's essentially the same as a function argument, holding whatever value the caller of `yield` passed.

Answer (score 38):

This was very strange to me too at first, but I hope this explanation/walkthru helps you.

The documentation [touches the subject](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/4/), in a quite good way - if my answer doesn't help I am sure their guide will.

First, fire up the Interactive Ruby interpreter by typing `irb` in your shell and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Type something like:

```
the_numbers = ['ett','tva','tre','fyra','fem'] # congratulations! You now know how to count to five in Swedish.
```

just so that we have an array to play with. Then we create the loop:

```
the_numbers.each do |linustorvalds|
    puts linustorvalds
end
```

It will output all the numbers, separated by newlines.

In other languages you'd have to write something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < the_numbers.length; i++) {
    linustorvalds = the_numbers[i]
    print linustorvalds;
}
```

The important things to note are that the `|thing_inside_the_pipes|` can be anything, as long as you are using it consistently. And understand that it is loops we are talking about, that was a thing I didn't get until later on.

Comment: In some "other languages" (Python), you write `for linustorvalds in the_numbers do print linustorvalds`. A bit more intuitive, perhaps.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I selected the C-style syntax because I suspect more people coming to ruby are familiar with that, but I hope they read your comment as well.

Comment: Thank you.  The "other languages" section helped me understand what was going on. +1.

Answer (score 7):

The code from the `do` to the `end` defines a [Ruby block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29#Blocks_and_iterators). The word `format` is a parameter to the block. The block is passed along with the method call, and the called method can `yield` values to the block.

See any text on Ruby for details, this is a core feature of Ruby that you will see all the time.

Comment: No, the code between the do and the end is a ruby block.  The terms between the vertical bars are parameters to that block.

Comment: IIRC, the pipe syntax is borrowed from Smalltalk.

Comment: Yep, except Smalltalk just used one pipe.

Answer (score 7):

```
@names.each do |name|
  puts "Hello #{name}!"
end
```

at http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/4/ is accompanied by this explanation:

> `each` is a method that accepts a block of code then runs that block of code for every element in a list, and the bit between `do` and `end` is just such a block. A block is like an anonymous function or `lambda`. The variable between pipe characters is the parameter for this block.
>
> What happens here is that for every entry in a list, `name` is bound to that list element, and then the expression `puts "Hello #{name}!"` is run with that name.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent in Java would be something like

```
// Prior definitions

interface RespondToHandler
{
    public void doFormatting(FormatThingummy format);
}

void respondTo(RespondToHandler)
{
    // ...
}

// Equivalent of your quoted code

respondTo(new RespondToHandler(){
    public void doFormatting(FormatThingummy format)
    {
        format.html();
        format.xml();
    }
});
```

Comment: Brent, if you mean by that, that the Java version is verbose and wordy - yep, I'd agree with you.  But then again, this is a less idiomatic construction in Java.  Ruby uses it all the time, Java less so.

Comment: the format.html(); format.xml(); part would probably be more like a switch statement, as you'd be switching on the format that was requested.

Comment: A cleaner example is the equivalent construction in JavaScript: respond_to(new function(format) { format.html(); format.xml(); });

I find Java's lack of true functor support really annoying; they aren't hard to use at all - unless you learned them with anonymous classes in Java!

Answer (score 3):

Parameters for a block sit between the `|` symbols.

Answer (score 2):

To make it even more clearer, if needed:

the pipe bars essentially make a new variable to hold the value generated from the method call prior. Something akin to:

*Original definition of your method:*

```
def example_method_a(argumentPassedIn)
     yield(argumentPassedIn + 200)
end
```

*How It's used:*

```
example_method_a(100) do |newVariable|
    puts newVariable;
end
```

It's almost the same as writing this:

```
newVariable = example_method_a(100) 
puts newVariable
```

where, newVariable = 200 + 100 = 300 :D!