# In Ruby, what are the vertical lines?

Tags: ruby

```
1.upto(9) { |x| print x }
```

Why won't this work?

```
{ print x |x} }
```

What about `y`?

Comment: What is everyone talking about parameters? what does that mean!? I'm not used to lambda expressions.

Comment: Parameters are the things you pass to a function. This isn't something special to lambdas. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_science%29

Comment: Is the |x| always written exactly right after the "{"?

Comment: Yes, always immediately after the `{`, or after the `do` if you are using `do` and `end` for your block.

Comment: I highly recommend you read "Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby" and the Ruby "Pickaxe" Book. Both are free; Google them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are those pipe symbols for in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665576/what-are-those-pipe-symbols-for-in-ruby)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's for the parameters that are being passed to your block. i.e. in your example, `upto` will call your block with each number from 1 to 9 and the current value is available as `x`.

The block parameters can have any name, just like method parameters. e.g. `1.upto(9) { |num| puts num }` is valid.

Just like parameters to a method you can also have multiple parameters to a block. e.g.

```
hash.each_pair { |key, value| puts "#{key} is #{value}" }
```

Answer (score 3):

The vertical lines are use to denote parameters to the block. The block is the code enclosed within { }. This is really the syntax of the ruby block, parameters to the block and then the code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an operator; it's delimiting the argument list for the block. The bars are equivalent to the parens in `def foo(x)`. You can't write it as `{print x |x}` for the same reason this:

```
def foo(x)
  puts "It's #{x}"
end
```

can't be rewritten as this:

```
def foo
  puts "It's #{x}" (x
end
```

Comment: What does that mean? I still don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

In the piece of code you have specified, vertical lines are a part of the block definition syntax. So `{ |x| print x }` is a block of code provided as a parameter to the `upto` method, `9` is also a parameter passed to the `upto` method.

Block of code is represented by a `lambda` or an object of class `Proc` in Ruby. `lambda` in this case is an anonymous function.

So just to draw an analogy to the function definition syntax,

```
def function_name(foo, bar, baz)
  # Do something
end


{       # def function_name (Does not need a name, since its anonymous)
|x|     #   (foo, bar, baz)
print x #   # Do Something
}       # end
```