# what does the vertical bar character do at the beginning of a method definition's name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was reading over some code and saw a method being defined in the following way (Ruby):

```
class BaseQuery
  def |(other)
    ChainedQuery.new do |relation|
      other.call(call(relation))
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried searching ruby docs, as well as SO, but can't find examples of "|" being used at the beginning of a method definition. Can someone please explain the purpose of beginning a method definition with "|" and the effect that it has on that method ?

Thank you so much, any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Ruby, what are the vertical lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545870/in-ruby-what-are-the-vertical-lines)

Comment: Can you refer a link where you find such sample?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That post is for the pipes simply containing block parameters...such as | x , y | . In this case, they use a single vertical bar as the first character for defining a method, which is considerably different.

Comment: @AntonTkachov this is the article https://www.sitepoint.com/7-design-patterns-to-refactor-mvc-components-in-rails/ . In the Query Objects section specifically

Comment: omg, i think it's just the method's name...yeah ? I was thinking maybe it had something to do with alternative block or lambda notations

Comment: @frostini yes, exactly.

Comment: Funny thing :) To be honest I've also haven't got it when saw it for the first time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'"|" being used at the beginning of a method definition' **indeed defines the method `|`**.

Comment: Right answer. In other words, operators like _Bitwise or_ or _Array union_ are Ruby methods, predefined in some classes. Here `class BaseQuery` defines the `or` operator with parameter `(other)` for it's own use.

Answer (score 1):

In [the site you linked to](https://www.sitepoint.com/7-design-patterns-to-refactor-mvc-components-in-rails/), the example method can be read as [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe) rather than `|`.

For more information, see [What are the restrictions for method names in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542354/what-are-the-restrictions-for-method-names-in-ruby)