# iterate through an array and display instance variables

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
class Person
  attr_reader = :name, :location
  def initialize(name, location)
    @name = name
    @location = location 
  end
end

persons_array = [Person.new("Shon", "Texas"), Person.new("Michael", "California"), Person.new("Chris, "california") ]
```

I am trying to iterate through the array above and display `"Shon is in Texas."` 
I tried `persons_array.each { puts "#{@name} is in "#{location}"`, but no luck.

Comment: Thanking everyone for submitting an answer is discourage on SO, for good reasons. Firstly, it's a waste of time for readers. Socondly, you don't want to encourage poor answers. Thirdly, if someone submits a killer answer and you say "Great answer!!", what are they to think? And lastly, if you forget to thank someone for their answer, readers may conclude you evidently don't like that one. Don't fell bad, many newcomers do this. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help) when you have time.

Comment: If you didn't have the read accessors, you could write: `[Person.new("Luke", "big trouble")].map { |obj| "#{obj.instance_variable_get(:@name)} is in #{obj.instance_variable_get(:@location)}" } 
=> ["Luke is in big trouble"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues with your code:

- the `attr_reader` line should not have the equals sign
- on the last line, in the block passed to `each` you have to declare the person variable between pipe signs (`|`)
- inside the `each` block you have to call the `name` and `location` accessors for the person instance, you don't have access to the local variables (ex: `@name`).

Here's the full code:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name, :location
  def initialize(name, location)
    @name = name
    @location = location 
  end
end

persons_array = [
    Person.new("Shon", "Texas"), 
    Person.new("Michael", "California"), 
    Person.new("Chris", "california") 
]

persons_array.each{ |p| puts "#{p.name} is in #{p.location}" }
```

And here's how it works: http://ideone.com/rMgpPd

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors.

It should be `attr_reader :name` and not `attr_reader = :name`. In fact, `attr_reader` is a method that takes in any number of arguments, and you can call it like so: `attr_reader(:name, :location)` which will still work.

You can take a look at how `|variable|` works in a Ruby block here: [What are those pipe symbols for in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665576/what-are-those-pipe-symbols-for-in-ruby)

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name, :location
  def initialize(name, location)
    @name = name
    @location = location 
  end
end

persons_array = [Person.new("Shon", "Texas"), Person.new("Michael", "California")]
persons_array.each do |person|
  puts "#{person.name} is in #{person.location}"
end
```

will print

```
Shon is in Texas
Michael is in California
```